# What points in a set meet the criteria for a closure point

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

In Luenberger's Optimization by Vector Space Methods, he defines a closure point as follows:

A point $x \in X$ is said to be a closure point of a set $P$ if, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a point $p \in P$ satisfying $||x - p|| < \epsilon$.

Because the collection of these points is called the closure of $P$, denoted $\overline{P}$, and a set is closed if $P = \overline{P}$, is it then true that any interior point is also a closure point by definition?

This seems to be true (to me) given the definition involving a normed distance.  If I took a unit circle with all points $x$ satisfying $||x|| \leq 1$ for instance, then for the point $x = (0.5, 0.5)$, there is surely **a** point $p$ such that $||x - p|| < \epsilon$ is satisfied, no?

In that case, what distinguishes a closed set from an open set?  Couldn't it be argued that for some open set $P$, there's some point infinitesimally close to the "official" closure that's contained in $P$, or is the fact that we can't quantify this point what ultimately means the set is not closed?

EDIT:

Maybe to rephrase my question a bit to better my understanding, what is it that distinguishes the closure points of an open set from that of a closed set?  Is it that the latter contains a quantifiable boundary?

Comment: Every interior point is a closure point. But the converse is not true in general. For instance 0 is a closure point of (0,1) but it is not an interior point.

Comment: The points of closure are the interior and the boundary.

Comment: Thanks, @Shahab!  So if I understand correctly, it’s really about how the set is defined?  For instance, a circle in $R^{2}$ containing all $x$ such that $||x|| < 1$ has closure points at $||x|| = 1$, but since these points aren’t also in the interior the set is open?

Comment: You should be careful thinking about points "infinitesimally close" and related phrases, in part because "infinitesimally small" things don't exist in standard treatments (eg there's no infinitesimally small real number)

Comment: Thanks, @perpetuallyconfused, just to make sure I understand, are you making the point I was teasing at the very end?  I think my conception was that since we can’t actually quantify an infinitesimally small value it doesn’t really “exist” and therefore can’t be a closure point?

Comment: even more basic: any element of P is a closure point for P. (This follows from your definition. See it?)

Comment: @hillard28 yes, in standard treatments "infinitesimally small/close" isn't something we can reason about. Now, _arbitrarily_ small/close things are a different matter, and is relevant for the related idea of a limit point